# Building phonegap app produces Identical filenames error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, mobile-application, phonegap-pushplugin

I have tried to build a phonegap app but each time, no matter which article I read talking about the config.xml, I get the identical filenames error. Below are screenshots of the phonegap view and its debug view.

[image]

[image]

Full Phonegap debug output below:

```
 Build Date: 2015-08-21 12:15:09 +0000
----------------------------------------------
Buildfile: /project/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.0

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: PushTest
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for PushTest...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for PushTest...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.0

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 98 source files to /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...
      [jar] Building jar: /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes.jar

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /project/CordovaLib/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /project/CordovaLib/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /project/CordovaLib/bin/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 48 source files to /project/bin/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: /project/bin/classes
      [dex] input: /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes.jar
      [dex] input: /project/libs/gcm.jar
      [dex] input: /project/libs/android-support-v13.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing /project/CordovaLib/bin/classes.jar -> classes-504f7b44a59440accd68683adc2cd1a7.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing /project/libs/gcm.jar -> gcm-e2d0c89b2f051bc00bf2436d8934b551.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing /project/libs/android-support-v13.jar -> android-support-v13-026801ff9f6ade972c4a53a8507422de.jar
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /project/bin/classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (137 defs/223.0KiB) with dex B (223 defs/326.3KiB). Result is 360 defs/670.8KiB. Took 0.3s
       [dx] Merged dex A (360 defs/670.8KiB) with dex B (4 defs/18.7KiB). Result is 364 defs/879.0KiB. Took 0.1s
       [dx] Merged dex A (364 defs/879.0KiB) with dex B (535 defs/572.2KiB). Result is 899 defs/1919.1KiB. Took 0.2s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /project/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /project/bin/res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-port-hdpi/splash.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-port-hdpi/splash.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-port-hdpi/splash.png: 69% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-port-ldpi/splash.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-port-ldpi/splash.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-port-ldpi/splash.png: 82% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-port-mdpi/splash.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-port-mdpi/splash.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-port-mdpi/splash.png: 97% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/splash.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/splash.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-port-xhdpi/splash.png: 109% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png: 51% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_next_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_previous_item.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_remove.png => /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_remove.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_action_remove.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: /project/res/drawable/icon.png => /project/bin/res/drawable/icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /project/bin/res/drawable/icon.png: 41% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 21 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...
     [aapt] /project/assets/www/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin: error: Directory is case-insensitive equivalent to: /project/assets/www/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:928: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:946: null returned: 1

Total time: 29 seconds
```